# how do i name a similar column from sql with different column names in a select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a column `'client_code'` in sql table `'tb_accounts'`. I want to create a `select` statement with two column aliases `'cl_code'` and `'acc_num'`, but all populated from the `'client_code'` column.

Comment: What's your question about this? What have you tried so far to resolve it?

Comment: Try using `SELECT client_code as acc_num, client_code as cl_code FROM tb_accounts`;

Comment: I wanted to know if something like `client_code as (cl_code,acc_num)` was possible not because am lazy but I have to repeat this for several columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select results are aliased like:

```
SELECT
acc.client_code as acc_num,
acc.client_code as cl_code
FROM
tb_accounts as acc
WHERE ....
```

Comment: If ithis solved your problem, an you sign my answer as answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider aliasing the same column with 2 different names. eg.

`select 'ABC' as firstname, 'ABC' as lastname from table`

Read more about aliasing here..
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL ALIASES** are used to create a temporary name for columns or tables.

```
SELECT A.client_code as `cl_code`, A.client_code as `acc_num` 
FROM tb_accounts as A WHERE condition;
```

**Syntax**

The syntax to *alias a column* in MySQL is:

```
column_name AS alias_name
```

The syntax to *alias a table* in MySQL is:

```
table_name AS alias_name
```

***Parameters or Arguments***

*column_name*:
The original name of the column that you wish to alias.

*table_name*:
The original name of the table that you wish to alias.

*AS*:
The temporary name to assign to the column or table.